# How to do it by simple sql or procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

object_tbl:

```
objId(primary key) | name
1                  | A
2                  | B  
3                  | C
```

document_tbl:

```
documentId | sourceId
1          | 2
2          | 2
3          | 1
4          | 3
5          | 3
6          | 3
```

objToDoc_tbl:

```
id | objectId | documentId
1  |    1     |    2
2  |    2     |    4
3  |    2     |    6
4  |    1     |    5
5  |    3     |    1
6  |    1     |    2
```

Inner join of all table

```
A   2    2
B   4    3
B   6    3
A   5    3
C   1    2
A   2    2

A     2
B     1
C     1
```

so Answer is 1(As A is only 2)

Question: - How many object are related to documents from multiple sources. 
How we can write sql query for this or it can only we solved by procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `join` all the tables and then use `having` to get objects with count > 1.

```
with t as (
select t.name, count(distinct d.sourceid) as count
from objtodoc_tbl o
join document_tbl d on o.documentid = d.documentid
join object_tbl t on o.objectid = t.name
group by t.name
having count(distinct d.sourceid) > 1
)
select count(t.name) from t;
```

Comment: i have to count the result

Comment: you mean number of objects having count > 1?

Comment: see the modified version.

Comment: is it supported on SQL2008, actually its not working

Comment: it is supported in SQL server 2008.